# Summation of Legendre symbol

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, characters

Let $\chi_{2,q}$ be the real Dirichlet character modulo a prime $q>2$, which is not the principal one (the so-called Legendre symbol). Is it true that 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{\chi_{2,q}(n)}{n} > 0
$$
? How can I prove it?

Comment: You are asking whether $L(1,\chi)$ is positive, where $L(s,\chi) = \sum_{n=1}\frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}$ is the Dirichlet $L$-function of some nonprincipal Dirichlet character $\chi$ modulo $q$. The fact that it doesn't vanish and is positive is well-known and is due to Dirichlet via the Dirichlet class number formula, but many other proofs are known - just search nonvanishing of $L(1,\chi)$.